# Start multiple console applications in a single window group?

Tags: windows-7, console, batch

I'm using a .cmd-file to start 5 instances of a service bus (using the "start" command in cmd). However, they are not the same executable.

Is there any way to group these windows into one taskbar object, from the .cmd-script?

Answer (score 1):

```
start "Title" cmd /c title srv1 & srv1.exe
start "Title" cmd /c title srv2 & srv2.exe
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But it would be nice to see which window runs which executable. :/

Comment: Easy. Answer updated.